# Notification can't accept channel id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In below code notification thing but it can't accept ..(firebase notification)

> Error:(82, 17) error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
>       required: Context
>       found: MyFirebaseMessagingService,String
>       reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) // error it cant accpet
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.esap)
                        .setContentTitle(messageBody.get("title"))
                        .setContentText(messageBody.get("message"))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Which version of the support library are you using? Should be at least 26.1.0.

Comment: 25.0.2 libarry version

Comment: That would be your problem. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)